# Add 1 in column according to specific dates and count

Tags: r, date, count

I have a table including a time series of daily values (value), Date and a column with "0s". Here are the variables:

```
value <- c(37,19.75,19.5,14.5,24.75,25,25.5,19.75,19.75,14.25,21.25,21.75,17.5,16.25,14.5,
           14.5,14.75,9.5,11.75,15.25,14.25,16.5,13.5,18.25,13.5,11.25,10.75,12,8.5,
           9.75,14.75)
Date <- c("1997-05-01","1997-05-02","1997-05-03","1997-05-04","1997-05-05",
          "1997-05-06","1997-05-07","1997-05-08","1997-05-09","1997-05-10",
          "1997-05-11","1997-05-12","1997-05-13","1997-05-14","1997-05-15",
          "1997-05-16","1997-05-17","1997-05-18","1997-05-19","1997-05-20",
          "1997-05-21","1997-05-22","1997-05-23","1997-05-24","1997-05-25",
          "1997-05-26","1997-05-27","1997-05-28","1997-05-29","1997-05-30",
          "1997-05-31")
ncol <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)`

data <- data.frame(value, Date, ncol)
```

Date is formatted as Date using the "as.Date" function. now I want to add "1" to the some values in column "newcol" (with 0s) on a specific 5 days, eg. on the "1997.05.05","1997.05.11","1997.05.14","1997.05.18","1997.05.25" in the time series.

I created this function, but works for a date only:

```
x <- 1
i <- which(format(data$Date, "%Y.%m.%d") == "1997.05.05") 
data$newcol[i] <- data$newcol[i] + x
```

how to do that best?

Then I would like to count the number of times that "value" appears >20 from a specific date (newcol = 1) for the previous 5 days. For example, the date 1997.05.25 how many times the value appears >20 to 1997.05.21.

Comment: You should probably avoid using `ncol` and `data` as variable names, since they could easily be mistaken for the `ncol()` function in `base` `r`, or `data()` in the `utils` package. It may be best to use names like `newcol`, `mydata`, `my_Date`, `my.value`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info @BarkleyBG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the 1st part of your question:

```
library(data.table)


setDT(data)[ Date %in% c("1997-05-05","1997-05-11","1997-05-14","1997-05-18","1997-05-25"), newcol := ncol+1 ]

# or perhaps better:

setDT(data)[, newcol := ifelse(Date %in% c("1997-05-05","1997-05-11","1997-05-14","1997-05-18","1997-05-25"), ncol+1, 0) ]
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot Rafael! You know how I could count the values (number of days with values >20 in the previous 5 days?

Comment: @Gustavo, I believe the second part of your problem is quite tricky and it probably deserves to be a separate question, something on lines of 'how to summarize / aggregate data by moving interval' . [There is a similar question to this here, you might want to take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719047/grouping-a-data-table-by-running-intervals)

Answer (score 0):

With `base R` this can be done

```
transform(data, newcol = as.integer(as.character(Date) %in% 
     c("1997-05-05","1997-05-11","1997-05-14","1997-05-18","1997-05-25")))
```